# NestJS verify AWS Cognito JWT: "TypeError: applicationRef.isHeadersSent is not a function"

Tags: typescript, authentication, nestjs, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito as the Authentication Service of my NestJS app. However, when I hit the endpoint without a JWT (not authenticated), the server always crashes and throws this error: `TypeError: applicationRef.isHeadersSent is not a function`, but it works well when a valid JWT is included, i.e., the correct data is returned by the API Endpoint protected by the auth guard. Below is how I constructed the authentication configuration and auth guard. Can someone please have a look? Thanks in advance!

*src/authz/authz.module.ts*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      issuer: 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx',
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: unknown): unknown {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

*src/authz/jwt.strategy.ts*

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })],
  providers: [JwtStrategy],
  exports: [PassportModule],
})
export class AuthzModule {}
```

*src/app.module.ts*

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { MomentModule } from './moment/moment.module';
import { graphqlConfigOptions } from './config/graphql';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { typeormConfigOptions } from './config/data-source';
import { CharacterModule } from './character/character.module';
import { AuthzModule } from './authz/authz.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot(graphqlConfigOptions),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeormConfigOptions),
    MomentModule,
    CharacterModule,
    AuthzModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*src/app.controller.ts*

```js
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiResponse, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@ApiTags('System')
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('health')
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: String })
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('secure-message')
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: String })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 401 })
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  getSecureMessage(): string {
    return this.appService.getSecureMessage();
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "moment-share-service",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "nest build && npx typeorm -d dist/src/config/data-source.js",
    "typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm:migration:generate -- migrations/migration"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.0",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^11.0.5",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^11.0.5",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.3.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.2",
    "ts-morph": "^18.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

*Stack Trace*

```
        if (!applicationRef.isHeadersSent(response)) {
                            ^
TypeError: applicationRef.isHeadersSent is not a function
    at ExceptionsHandler.catch (D:\self-study\GitHub Repo\Social Media App Suite\social-media-app-suite\moment-share-service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\base-exception-filter.js:27:29)
    at ExceptionsHandler.next (D:\self-study\GitHub Repo\Social Media App Suite\social-media-app-suite\moment-share-service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\exceptions-handler.js:16:20)
    at D:\self-study\GitHub Repo\Social Media App Suite\social-media-app-suite\moment-share-service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:13:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

*result of `npx nest info`*

```
[System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v18.14.1
YARN Version    : 1.22.17 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 8.2.8 

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 8.4.7
mapped-types version     : 1.2.2
schematics version       : 8.0.11
passport version         : 9.0.3
graphql version          : 11.0.5
swagger version          : 6.3.0
typeorm version          : 9.0.1
testing version          : 8.4.7
apollo version           : 11.0.5
common version           : 9.4.0
config version           : 2.3.1
core version             : 9.4.0
cli version              : 8.2.8
```

Comment: can you share some stack trace?

Comment: also, what's the output of `npx nest info`? I want to see if you got your versions aligned.

Comment: Hi Micael, thank you for your reply. I have updated the question to include stack trace and the output of `npx nest info`, as well as the package.json

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that all NestJS related packages are using the same major versions; for ex. this combination triggers the same issue for me:

```
"@nestjs/core": "^9.4.2"`
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
```

In your case, either use `9.*.*` or `8.*.*`:

```
[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 8.2.8 

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 8.4.7  <----- 8.*.*
mapped-types version     : 1.2.2
schematics version       : 8.0.11
passport version         : 9.0.3
graphql version          : 11.0.5
swagger version          : 6.3.0
typeorm version          : 9.0.1
testing version          : 8.4.7
apollo version           : 11.0.5
common version           : 9.4.0  <----- 9.*.*
config version           : 2.3.1
core version             : 9.4.0  <----- 9.*.*
cli version              : 8.2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```js
validate(payload: unknown)
```

to

```js
validate(req: Request, payload: unknown)
```

Comment: Please explain the effect of the change you propose and how it solves the problem. Try for [answer] and consider taking the [tour] please.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **exception filters** when I encountered this error,

```js
@Catch()
export class PrismaExceptionFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: PrismaClientKnownRequestError, host: ArgumentsHost) {

        // this call caused the error
        super.catch(exception, host);

        // other sections of code
    }
}
```

Inside the `main.ts` where I registered the filter globally,
the issue was fixed by changing this:

```js
app.useGlobalFilters(new PrismaExceptionFilter())
```

to

```js
const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);

app.useGlobalFilters(new PrismaExceptionFilter(httpAdapter))
```